# How can i take email and password from database? I can't validate users in Spring security

Tags: java, mysql, spring, security, jpa

*Stacktrace*
*Why i have java.lang.NullPointerException in UserDetailsServiceImplementation when i try call method loadUserByUsername in line AdminUser user = (AdminUser) jpaUserDao.findUserByEmail(username);*

```
`2016-02-13 15:08:52 ERROR UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:226 - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.softserveinc.ita.redplatform.business.service.UserDetailsServiceImplementation.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImplementation.java:39)
at   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
... 41 more`
```

*spring-security.xml*

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/adm/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/red/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN',  'ROLE_REDADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/index" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="email"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />

</http>

<beans:bean id="UserDetailsServiceImplementation"
        class="com.softserveinc.ita.redplatform.business.service.UserDetailsServiceImplementation">
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="UserDetailsServiceImplementation">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

 </beans:beans>
```

*persistance.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-     package="com.softserveinc.ita.redplatform.persistence.dao.impl" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JPAUnit" />

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.softserveinc.ita.redplatform.common.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop     key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

*JPAAdminUserDao find user by email*

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JPAAdminUserDao extends JPAGenericDao<AdminUser, Long> 
   implements AdminUserDao {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManagerFactoryBean;

public final AdminUser findUserByEmail(final String email) {
    List<AdminUser> users = new ArrayList<AdminUser>();
    users = (List<AdminUser>) entityManagerFactoryBean
            .createQuery("from " + AdminUser.class.getName() 
                    + " as user where user.email=:email")
            .setParameter("email", email).getResultList();
    if (users.size() > 0) {
        return users.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPAAdminUserDao dao = new JPAAdminUserDao();
    dao.findUserByEmail("rom23");
}
}
```

*UserDetailsServiceImplementation*

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImplementation implements UserDetailsService     {

private AdminUserDao jpaUserDao;

 @Override
public final UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) 
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    AdminUser user = (AdminUser) jpaUserDao.findUserByEmail(username);
    if (user instanceof AdminUser) {
        set.add(new String("ROLE_USER"));
        set.add(new String("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        set.add(new String("ROLE_REDADMIN"));
    } else {
        set.add(new String("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(set);
    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

}

private User buildUserForAuthentication(final AdminUser user, 
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, 
            true, true, true, authorities);
}


private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(final 
        Set<String> userRoles) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    // Build user's authorities
    for (String userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole));
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> result = new 
            ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return result;
}

public final AdminUserDao getJpaUserDao() {
    return jpaUserDao;
}

public final void setAdminUserDao(final AdminUserDao newJpaUserDao) {
    this.jpaUserDao = newJpaUserDao;
}
}
```

Comment: Posting whole stack trace here is no way use full. Post some relevant code if you expect some answer from others.

Comment: Not as comment, edit your question..

Comment: @Roma Edit your question to include the overall goal, desired behavior, necessary code, and target system. Otherwise your question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with this line of code:

```
AdminUser user = (AdminUser) jpaUserDao.findUserByEmail(username);
```

Simply `jpaUserDao` is not injected.
you have to set `jpaUserDao` in bean declaration, like:

```
<beans:bean id="UserDetailsServiceImplementation"
        class="com.softserveinc.ita.redplatform.business.service.UserDetailsServiceImplementation">
  <property name="adminUserDao" ref="jpaUserDao" />
</beans:bean>
```

and make sure that `jpaUserDao` is also declared

Comment: Now i have other proplem

Comment: 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.softserveinc.ita.redplatform.persistence.dao.impl.JPAAdminUserDao.findUserByEmail(JPAAdminUserDao.java:36)
 at com.softserveinc.ita.redplatform.business.service.UserDetailsServiceImplementation.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImplementation.java:41)
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
 ... 41 more'